# symfony 2.7 debug display default message

Tags: symfony, debugging, symfony-2.7

I've just upgraded from Symfony 2.3 to symfony 2.7 and I don't understand how to set debug mode in app.php and app_dev.php files to display a default error message as it is defined in Symfony\Component\Debug\ExceptionHandler sendPhpResponse method, called in failSafeHandle method.

Using demo bundle I made the following tests (with results):

```
Kernel  Debug   display

in case of fatal error (assignment without value):

true    null    php error message + symfony error message
false   null    php error message

true    true    symfony error message
false   true    php error message

true    false   symfony error message
false   false   php error message

in case of exception (throw new exception)

true    null    symfony error message
false   null    php error message

true    true    symfony error message
false   true    php error message

true    false   symfony error message
false   false   php error message

in case of notice (array index not existent):

true    null    symfony error message
false   null    php error message

true    true    symfony error message
false   true    blank page

true    false   symfony error message
false   false   blank page
```

So I was wondering which parameter configuration would display a default error message.

Comment: debug=false & overwriting the default error view. see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html

Comment: no, in case of notice in production environment it's displayed a blank page, debug component doesn't seem to be used.